# Product of permutations in $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Consider the elements $(1,2)(2,3)$ and $(2,3)(1,2)$ in $S_3$. We have that they equal $(1,3,2)$ and $(1,2,3)$ respectively. I am unable to make sense out of this.

For the first product, let $\sigma = (1,2)$ and $\sigma'=(2,3)$. To be completely clear, I will write $\sigma=
  (\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    2 & 1 & 3\\
  \end{smallmatrix})$ and $\sigma'=
  (\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    1 & 3 & 2\\
  \end{smallmatrix})$

Computing for $\sigma(\sigma'(1))$, we have that $1 \to 1$ in $\sigma'$ and $1 \to 2$ in $\sigma$. Therefore, $\sigma(\sigma'(1)) = 2$. Using the same system, we have that $\sigma(\sigma') = \sigma\sigma' =  (\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    2 & 3 & 1\\
  \end{smallmatrix}) = (1,2,3)$

As for the second product, I get the result $(1,3,2)$. In other words, according to my calculations, the answers should be the other way around. I understand that there must be a fundamental flaw in my understanding of permutations here, but I am unable to see it.

Comment: Apparently(?) the book/lecture uses the convention that the permutation on the left is the one to be applied first, so $\sigma\tau = \tau\circ\sigma$.

Comment: Hm, no, I am positive we are working with the opposite. It might just be a blunder from their side, if my calculations are indeed correct? (I need this sigh of relief.)

Comment: Yes, if your text's convention is that the permutation on the right is performed first, then you're correct in your reasoning. There must be a blunder on their side, as you aptly put it.

Comment: Your calculations are correct. Either the book accidentally switched the two answers or Daniel's suspicion is right. Note you never cited your source, only referred to it mysteriously as "their side" ...

Comment: Yes, I have no intention of telling who blundered as its not a book nor a text.

Comment: Should this question stay as a note on the potential differences for other people or should I delete it?

Comment: Don't delete it.